# How to manipulate DOM using angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ejs

So basically i have a variable in my controller $scope.choose:

What i want is that depending upon value of this variable,I want to modify html view

Something like this implemented in ejs

```
<% if($scope.choose==1){%>
<div>
Condition true {{choose}}
</div>
<%}else{&>
<div>
Condition false {{choose}}
</div>
<%}%>
```

I dont know if this code is correct but I hope you get what I am trying to achieve using only angular w/o ejs

Comment: It is very bad idea to use two templates engine in application. Why do you use it?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ng-if` directive or `ng-switch` :

```
<div ng-if="choose">
   Condition true
</div>
<div ng-if="!choose">
   Condition false
</div>
```

`ng-if` evaluates a boolean and `ng-switch` a value:

```
<div ng-switch="choose">
  <div ng-switch-when="1">
    choose = 1
  </div>
  <div ng-switch-when="2">
    choose = 2
  </div>
</div>
```

See [ng-if doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) and [ng-switch doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch).